# Why dateparser module fails to parse date strings in Spanish even setting parameters as languages or locales in Spanish?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dateparser

I'm trying to parse a large set of files with records that include dates in Spanish with formats like this one 'Ago 01, 2022'. For this task, I'm using the function `parse` from `dataparser` module. In the past, I could use successfully that function for a similar purpose, but now it fails with string in Spanish even if I set languages or locales parameters for `parse` function.

I import the function `parse` with this line:

```py
from dateparser import parse
```

1. If I call the function with a date in English it run successfully, as I expect:

```py
parse('Aug 01, 2021', date_formats=['%b %d, %Y'] )

# Returns
datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 1, 0, 0)
```

2. If I call the function with a date in Spanish without any other parameter it runs unsuccessfully, as I expect too:

   (*August* in Spanish is *Agosto*):

```py
parse('Ago 01, 2021', date_formats=['%b %d, %Y'] )

# Raises an exception in regex that ends with:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\regex\_regex_core.py in _compile_replacement(source, pattern, is_unicode)
   1735                 return False, [value]
   1736 
-> 1737         raise error("bad escape \\%s" % ch, source.string, source.pos)
   1738 
   1739     if isinstance(source.sep, bytes):

error: bad escape \d at position 7
```

I suppose that this error has something related to a regex pattern in Spanish, but I cannot be sure what is the problem beyond the language.

3. Giving to `parse` a language parameter doesn't change the results.

```py
parse('Ago 01, 2021', date_formats=['%b %d, %Y'], languages=['es'])

# Raises the same exception that ends with:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\regex\_regex_core.py in _compile_replacement(source, pattern, is_unicode)
   1735                 return False, [value]
   1736 
-> 1737         raise error("bad escape \\%s" % ch, source.string, source.pos)
   1738 
   1739     if isinstance(source.sep, bytes):

error: bad escape \d at position 7
```

4. Something similar occurs if I set the parameter locales.

```py
parse('Ago 01, 2021', date_formats=['%b %d, %Y'], locales=['es'])

# Raises the same exception that ends with:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\regex\_regex_core.py in _compile_replacement(source, pattern, is_unicode)
   1735                 return False, [value]
   1736 
-> 1737         raise error("bad escape \\%s" % ch, source.string, source.pos)
   1738 
   1739     if isinstance(source.sep, bytes):

error: bad escape \d at position 7
```

---

I'm not sure if the problem is related to an update or a change in the module, but I want to mention that when I call `parse` for the first time, I get this warning message.

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateparser\utils\__init__.py:130: PytzUsageWarning: The localize
method is no longer necessary, as this time zone supports the fold attribute (PEP 495). 
For more details on migrating to a PEP 495-compliant implementation, see 
https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html
date_obj = tz.localize(date_obj)
```

Looking for an insight I tried to use a `dateparser`'s demo located in this URL https://dateparser-demo.netlify.app/ cited in this github's repository  https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser cited in PyPi https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/. But, in this demo, my string in Spanish is successfully parsed. I supposed that I have an old version of dateparser so I checked and I have the latest version available in PyPi.

- I'm using `python` 3.7.3 and `dateparser` 1.1.1 (currently the latest) on a machine with Windows 10 in Spanish.

Comment: For what it's worth: I ran your example 1 and 3 on an macOS (English) with Python 3.7.13 and dateparser 1.1.1 without error. Although I do get the `PytzUsageWarning`, but that's so far just a warning. And the resulting date is correct. Makes me wonder if Windows is to blame here.

Comment: The examples on the PyPI page don't show any use of `date_formats` argument. Since the error mentions `\b`, and there is a `%b` in the format, could you try without: `parse('Ago 01, 2021', languages=['es'])`?

Comment: Apparently related: https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/issues/1052 . It appears a fix is suggested in https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/pull/1067 , but that is not in yet, and alalso well past the release of 1.1.1.

Comment: Given the comments in the GitHub issues, you could try to downgrade the `regex` module by a few (minor) versions. I can't tell you which one exactly, because the internal versioning doesn't match what is on PyPI, so while my local regex version is not the most recent (and works properly), I don't know which PyPI version it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in recent versions.
`dateparser            1.1.3`
Can you check that everything is working as expected now?

```py
>>> parse('Ago 01, 2021', date_formats=['%b %d, %Y'] )
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0)
>>> parse('Ago 01, 2021', date_formats=['%b %d, %Y'], languages=['es'])
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0)
>>> parse('Ago 01, 2021', date_formats=['%b %d, %Y'], locales=['es'])
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0)
```